# How to use switch case with Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, switch-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to print a value using switch-case base off of what the user selected. I can easily print what the user selected in the spinner but I need the value that goes with it. I'm hoping I'm just missing something small in my code.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText input1;
    Spinner answer;
    Object value;
    int yourInt = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        input1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        answer = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spinner1);
        ((Button) findViewById (R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        answer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    yourInt = 1;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    yourInt = 2;
                    break;
                }

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
    public void onClick (View v) {

        input1.setText(yourInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: **input1.setText(yourInt);** this can be in switch case too...

Comment: in this code it looks like spinner is empty

Comment: The spinner has no adapter associated with it?

Comment: I have a string-array. I set it in the xml.

Comment: This would also work: 
`int index;
index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                switch (index) {
case 0:

case 1:
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch (position) {
            case 0:
                yourInt = 1;
                input1.setText(""+yourInt);
                break;

            case 1:
                yourInt = 2;
                input1.setText(""+yourInt);
                break;
            }
```

Comment: I did this and it just force close when I tried to start the app.

Comment: k now check edit i have added your int with a string (""+yourInt)try it i m waiting for your responce. and please also try to show logcat here.

Comment: Awesome man, that work just by adding (""+yourInt). Even though it was pushing it to my edittext without me pushing the button but I just moved the input1.setText(""+yourInt) into the void onClick and it works how I want it too. Thanks a lot. Mind explaining why just adding ""+ made it work instead of the way before.

Comment: mView.setText(String str);   set text method take a string type place of int type.